# Can someone explain what is in XML file, and what is it for?

Tags: xml, vba, caching, intersystems-cache

I have an XML file with 30 000 lines of code which I don't have any idea what it can be. My goal is to identify what this XML for. Whether it is a dump of Cache(Intersystems) Database, or some source code..I don't know, I am just assuming. Then I started to copy-paste into google to find what programming language it might be, and could not figure it out. So I came here for help.

```
<Method name="xmlStartProcessRequestOLD">
<Description>Сохранил на всякий случай метод (изменял основной метод из     за ошибки )</Description>
<FormalSpec>xmlStream:%CharacterStream</FormalSpec>
<ReturnType>%String</ReturnType>
<Implementation><![CDATA[
        set res = ""
        set xml = xmlStream.Read()

        set docType = ..extractAndDecodeTagValue(xml, "docType")
        s ^lol($i(^lol),"ESEDO","docType") = docType
        set href = ..extractAndDecodeTagValue(xml, "href")
        set from = ..extractAndDecodeTagValue(xml, "from")

        // about a 100 lines of code, which I intentionally skipped

 q res
 ]]></Implementation>
 </Method>
 </Class>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you provide `extractAndDecodeTagValue` method code?

Comment: And contents on xml file

Comment: Most likely the code extracts attributes values from some node

Comment: It's really not very clear what you are asking, or what you are trying to solve. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand how to ask a good question that will attract good answers.

Comment: I have an XML file with 30 000 lines of code which I don't have any idea what it can be. My goal is to identify what this XML for. Whether it is a dump of Cache(Intersystems) Database, or some source code.. I started to copy-paste into google to find what programming language it might be, and could not figure it out. So I came here for help.

Comment: Where you got this file ?

Comment: @DAiMor from my boss.. any ideas about the code?

Comment: This code was written in our company, please contact with us

Answer (score 4):

It is a fragment of source code for some class in Caché. All sources in Caché can be exported and imported in XML format. To import that file, you can open Studio, and with drag-and-drop or with menu "Инструменты->Импортировать локально" or by hotkey Ctrl+I. With command in terminal/csession
`do $system.OBJ.Load("your file.xml")`
If you  need more details, you can ask in russian [here](http://www.sql.ru/forum/cache)